# Reverse estimating 3 numbers from mean and n

Tags: python, math, statistics, average, mean

I am trying to work out the n for three categories from the mean average and total number. I basically have the below:

```
    Price   n
A   160.17  ?
B   162.06  ?
C   140     ?

Total n:    27

Avg price:  156.95
```

For this one it comes out as A - 3, B - 18, C - 6. I basically found this out by trial and error but was wondering if there is a more targeted way?

Due to rounding errors it may also not come out exactly, so ideally I would be after the minimum error. I mostly work in Python but can happily run with pseudo-code or any ideas people have.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to formulaicly solve in the general case.  If you let the number of items of A, B, and C be a, b, and c, respectively, this situation gives you the equations:

a + b + c = 27

160.17*a + 162.06 * b + 140* c = 27 * 156.95

This is two equations, but you are trying to solve for three variables.  If you really need to know the answers are are sure that all of a, b, and c are pretty small (under 30) and integer, you could loop through all possibilities to brute force it, but I would advise against it.